# God save the Queen

Tags: idioms, verb-agreement, subjunctive-mood, conjugation

I was wondering why this expression is not “God *saves* the Queen”. According to my very first English teacher, when the subject is *he*, *she* or *it*, “to save” is conjugated “he/she/it saves”.

Is it an exception?

Comment: God help us all.

Comment: @fralau You see this issue is like Handel's Hallelujah chorus: it's going to go on forever and ever.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is not an exception. This is the subjunctive mood, being used to express a wish. See “Third person requests with a main-clause subjunctive” in the [*Wikipedia* article](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/English_subjunctive#Third_person_requests_with_a_main-clause_subjunctive) on “English subjunctive”, which gives “God save our gracious Queen” as a specific example.

You may think of it as short for “*May* God save the Queen” or “*Let* God save the Queen” if that helps you parse it better.

Comment: +1.  Good answer.  Just a small note - it's the subjunctive __mood__, not case.  Cases are about the declension of nouns and adjectives (nominative, accusative etc).

Comment: Or as an imperative: God, save the Queen!

Comment: @brad: yeah, probably more likely, humans have always been a bit keen to dictate the will of deities :P

Comment: @Brad: I would call it [*exhortative*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hortative) rather than *imperative*

Comment: Surely we should say "God *please* save the Queen"

Comment: @mgb: That's partly why it's definitely not imperative/exhortative: it's "May/Let God save the queen" rather than "God, [please] save the queen".

Comment: Later on in the verse is 'May she defend the laws..', which makes it fairly clear that it is a normal subjunctive.

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer! I *be* totally satified with it.

Answer (score 14):

It’s because *save* is subjunctive. In particular, it’s an example of the ‘formulaic subjunctive’, found in other fixed expressions such as *Heaven forbid* and *come what may*. It is used in *God Save The Queen* to express a non-factual concept: we cannot assume that God saves The Queen, but we express the hope that he will.