# confusion in two sentences of present simple

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subjunctive-mood

As we know that there is a sentence "Allah says" this sentence is correct, but when we say "God bless you" why not " God blesses you"

Comment: It's an archaic use of the subjunctive which still lives on in this fixed idiom. It means *"may God bless you"*.

Comment: Essentially duplicate http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66020/god-save-the-queen

Answer (score 2):

*God bless you* is not in the present simple, it's in the subjunctive.

> (*May) God bless you!*

Comment: A rather archaic form of the subjunctive at that, surviving because it is a commonly expression.

Comment: @JonHanna Indeed. "God save the Queen" and "Long live the King" are other examples of that rather archaic form of subjunctive.

Answer (score 0):

God bless you is contracted: **May** God bless you ... (for whatever you have done that has caused me to say 'God bless you').

Comment: It's not contracted, the subjunctive "God bless you" means the same thing as "may God bless you", without the use of the modal *may*. Likewise "bless you" means "may you be blessed", but there's no way to express that in a form using *may* without also changing the phrase further than just its addition.

Comment: @JonHanna does it mean the same because the may is inferred, or entirely on its own merit? I understand it as a contraction because I internally add the (what I consider implicit) 'may' so that the sentence makes sense to me.

Comment: Entirely on its own merit. As late as Early Modern English, it would often be spelt "God blesse you" rather than e.g. "God will bless you", a legacy of even greater differences earlier still, but which became increasingly less consistent and left the language, with this form of the subjunctive now rare outside of set phrases.